# How to make gridview item take double width in GridView in Android

Tags: android, gridview

How to make gridview item fill 2 columns space.
Lets say i have object property ( isBig ), and i have arraylist of these objects.
and when filling the adapter data, if i found ( isBig == true ) this object will fill 2 columns space.

My GridView is 4 Columns.
i'm trying AsymmetricGridView and StaggeredGridView .. but it doesnot work yet. So any Solution guys.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager instead. There, you can specify where you want to have "big" items instead of regular ones.

Look here
http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html